# How to use Permutations to create a set order of items

Tags: combinatorics

So for an Assignment, we are doing maximum amount of combinations with pizzas out of certain ingredients, bases, cheeses and sauces. The normal solution would be to just use: nCr * bases * cheeses * sauces. But this does not specify the order of things on the pizza, it would imply that it can be done in any order, with cheese on bottom or ingredients on top. So can permutations be used to array the items in order of Base|Sauce|Amount of ways to order the chosen 6 Ingredients (for each scenario)|Cheeses|. If so, or some other method exists, wondering if it is known?

For information amounts are here:

Bases amount = 4

Sauces amount = 3

Cheese amount = 2 * 2! (Option of extra cheese or no extra cheese)

Ingredients amount = 14 (6 ingredients allowed per pizza)

Comment: Try to write your question using MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit ambiguous, so let me first write the hypothesis that I will assume:

**Problem A)**

Count the total number of pizza´s recipes that can be made when using:

- $1$ out of $4$ bases.
- $1$ out of $3$ sauces.
- $1$ out of $2$ cheeses.
- $1$ (or none) out of $2$ cheeses (this is the optional extra cheese).
- Up to $6$ out of $14$ ingredients (when mixing these ingredients the order does not matter).

I will also assume that the 'mixing' order does **NOT** matter (the arrangement 'base -> sauce -> cheese -> ingredients' is equivalent to 'base -> cheese -> sauce -> ingredients').

The total ammount of recipes will be $$\dbinom{4}{1}\cdot\dbinom{3}{1}\cdot\dbinom{2}{1}\cdot\underbrace{\left[ \dbinom{2}{0}+\dbinom{2}{1}\right]}_{Extra\text{ } cheese}\cdot\underbrace{\left[ \dbinom{14}{0}+\dbinom{14}{1}+\dbinom{14}{2}+\dbinom{14}{3}+\dbinom{14}{4}+\dbinom{14}{5}+\dbinom{14}{6}\right]}_{Ingredients}$$

**Problem B)**

Count the total number of pizza´s recipes that can be made when using:

- $1$ out of $4$ bases.
- $1$ out of $3$ sauces.
- $1$ out of $2$ cheeses.
- $1$ (or none) out of $2$ cheeses (this is the optional extra cheese).
- Up to $6$ out of $14$ ingredients (when mixing these ingredients the order does not matter).

I will also assume that the 'mixing' order **DOES** matter (the arrangement 'base -> sauce -> cheese -> ingredients' is **NOT** equivalent to 'base -> cheese -> sauce -> ingredients').

The total ammount of recipes will be $$\dbinom{4}{1}\cdot\dbinom{3}{1}\cdot\dbinom{2}{1}\cdot\underbrace{\left[ \dbinom{2}{0}+\dbinom{2}{1}\right]}_{Extra\text{ } cheese}\cdot\underbrace{\left[ \dbinom{14}{0}+\dbinom{14}{1}+\dbinom{14}{2}+\dbinom{14}{3}+\dbinom{14}{4}+\dbinom{14}{5}+\dbinom{14}{6}\right]}_{Ingredients}\cdot 5!$$
since every base-sauce-chese-extra_cheese-ingredient setting can be rearranged into $5!$ different settings.

Comment: Perfect, I get it now, the way you had approached the question was correct, and unfortunately yes the question was worded badly.